# How can I inject value into angular without reloading with debug info?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to set value inside an angular's object. At the moment I have

```
angular.element('query-bar').scope().state.query.query = document.getElementsByClassName('kuiLocalSearchInput')[0].value;
```

which does work but requires me to reload application using

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()
```

. I don't know much about angular, but I assume there are performance implications, so I would like to avoid it. How can I achieve my objective of setting the value without reloading with debug info?

Comment: you should not modify the scope from the outside. If you have to provide a value at the start of your application, use angular.config or angular.run . If you have to provide a value during the running of your app, you have to provide a function to call from the outside. For example you could inside your desired controller write `window.myFunctionFromOutside = function() { $scope.$apply(function() { ... do whatever you want here ... }); }`. In your console you can write `window.myFunctionFromOutside()` and it will trigger it. $scope.$apply has to be called to make angular check scope val change

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, `<input>` elements use the `ng-model` directive to put their values on `$scope` objects.

Comment: The question is too broad. We need to know more about what the app is doing to show you how to integrate it with the AngularJS framework. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot change the app, I'm just making [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that fixes some performance issues in the application to make it usable. But I have no control over. Assigning this one variable fixes my issue though, so I wondered if there is a way to do it without debug info. I think the question is actually very specific: how to assign to object inside angular scope from outside without enabling debug information?